# network with all the interactions of the alpha-synuclein protein

Tags: proteins, biological-networks

I would like to make a network with all the interactions of the alpha-synuclein protein (in homo sapiens), that is, I would like to visualize the pathways where this protein participates, I would also want to include in the network the genes that encode this protein.
I would like to make this network in cytoscape. Could someone tell me where I can find a guide to do this.
thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I just started using cytoscape. What I don't know is how to obtain the pathways in which the alpha synuclein participates from cytoscape (or if there is a way to download them and then import them into cytoscape). I would like to create a node with the name snca (which is the alpha synuclein), then, from that node, get the pathways where the alpha synuclein participates, but I don't know how to achieve this

Comment: In other words, I would like to build an Enrichment Map, which would show the different pathways in which the alpha synuclein involved is found (both in diseases and physiologically), that is, each node would be a pathway, but each node, too, would be a subnetwork, I should be able to view each of these subnetworks. Excuse me for the question but I am just starting in this field